# YII Mail Generate unwanted ascii code in HTML mail

Tags: yii, swiftmailer

I use YII-Mail just by copying the sample but I always get some ascii charcters in my generated links
Where they come from and how to avoid them ?

```
$message = new YiiMailMessage;
$message->view = 'mail';
$message->setBody(array('model'=>$model), 'text/html');
$message->subject = Yii::t('tr','my subject');
$message->addTo('me@me.com');
$message->from = 'you@you.com';
Yii::app()->mail->send($message);
```

and in view file 'mail'

```
<h1><?php echo(Yii::t('tr','This is HTML mail')); ?></h1>
<?php echo CHtml::link('Mylink', array('controller/view', 'id'=>$model->id)); ?>
```

The resulted email source looks like this

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<h1>Incoming goods</h1>
<a href=3D"/testdrive/index.php?r=3Dcontroller/v=iew&amp;id=3D234137">Mylink</a>
```

You could notice the 3D just after the = sign. It would have been more logical if I had the sign = OR the code 3D kind of a conversion needed but here I have both of them which is quite puzzling...

Comment: I update the question and add the header of the mail received to show the header type seems correctly set for HTML. Also I maybe, should specify the computer has Chinese language installed.

Answer (score 0):

In fact the extra characters are quoted-printable encoding, I was thinking they where the reason why the link in email could not work. But in fact the link did not work because it is relative link not absolute ! So using the correct

```
Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl
```

in the link will do the job perfectly.